# Dual Boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, mountpoint

I want to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 8. Both are installed in my Dell laptop but the bios is not configured properly. I have to press F11 every time I need to use Ubuntu instead of Windows 8. I tried to use Boot Repair to repair it but was unsuccessful.

Here the the output from my boot repair : http://paste.ubuntu.com/7390841/

Also, the Boot Repair said that :

```
The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)
```

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: If this is a computer that shipped from the factory with Win 8, then BIOS is not a concern -- in order for a computer to be Win 8 certified it must be UEFI-compliant. That said, have a look at your system setup ("BIOS"/UEFI) and change the boot order. You should see a few entries, two of which would be "Ubuntu" and "Windows Boot Manager". Just move Ubuntu to the top and voila!

Comment: After perusing your Boot Repair log, I see that it is, in fact, UEFI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Enter the UEFI setup (usually <kbd>F1</kbd>,<kbd>Delete</kbd>,<kbd>F12</kbd>, etc.)
2. Go to the Boot tab
3. Move "Ubuntu" up to the top of the list
4. Reboot